# Woocommerce order page - Change background colour for processing order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using Wordpress & Woocommerce
I want to change the background of the table when a new order is received and shows as 'Processing' as shown in my picture included below.

(Example: tr#post-441 {background-color: #bbff7d;}  )

[Background colour on table on woocommerce orders PROCESSING only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPIVM.png)

I know there's ways to effect this via the functions.php file and have searched and searched but just need a helping hand to get it to change colour.

This would be a finishing touch to a project so any help is massively appreciated.
Many thanks
- Ash

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in theme functions.php file

```
function change_order_processing_row_color(){?>

 <style type="text/css">
 .status-wc-processing {
        background: green !important;
        color: white !important;
       }
     </style>

   <?php }

   add_action('admin_head','change_order_processing_row_color');
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody want to change color of all statuses in orders, then you can do it like this:

```
order-procesing - red
on-hold - orange
failed - grey
completed - green
```

Add this code to bottom of your child theme functions.php file:

```
function change_order_processing_row_color(){?>

    <style type="text/css">
        .status-wc-processing {
               background: #e98787 !important;
               color: white !important;
              }
    
        .status-wc-on-hold {
               background: #ffd88a !important;
               color: white !important;
              }

        .status-wc-failed {
               background: #999999 !important;
               color: white !important;
              }
    
        .status-wc-completed {
               background: #aad17d !important;
               color: white !important;
              }
            </style>
       
          <?php }
       
          add_action('admin_head','change_order_processing_row_color');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better i think:

```
    function change_order_processing_row_color(){?>

  <style type="text/css">
      .order-status.status-processing {
                background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #017621 8%, #00CC37 100%);
    border-color: #0C9F34;
    border-radius: 360 px !important;
    padding: 360 px;
         color: white;
}
 .status-wc-completed { 
  background-color: transparent;
    background-image: #00CC37;
    border-color: #0C9F34;
    border-radius: 360 px !important;
    padding: 360 px;
         color: white;
    
       }
     .order-preview {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #017621 8%, #00CC37 100%);
    border-color: #0C9F34;
    border-radius: 360 px !important;
    padding: 360 px;
         color: white;
}
.post-type-shop_order .wp-list-table .order-preview, .woocommerce_page_wc-orders .wp-list-table .order-preview {
    border: none!important;
    border-radius: 360px!important;
}
      .order-preview:hover {
       background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #005617 0%, #00CC37 100%);
          color: white;
}
      
    .post-type-shop_order .wp-list-table tbody td, .post-type-shop_order .wp-list-table tbody th, .woocommerce_page_wc-orders .wp-list-table tbody td, .woocommerce_page_wc-orders .wp-list-table tbody th {

    color: black;
}
     .post-type-shop_order .wp-list-table .column-billing_address .description, .post-type-shop_order .wp-list-table .column-shipping_address .description, .woocommerce_page_wc-orders .wp-list-table .column-billing_address .description, .woocommerce_page_wc-orders .wp-list-table .column-shipping_address .description {
    display: block;
    color: blue;
         font-weight:600;
}
     .order-view{
color:black;
}    

      


   <?php }

   add_action('admin_head','change_order_processing_row_color');
```